# When is the quote object is generated in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, quote

I believe it should be made when we add an item in cart, but I need to find code in Magento core where quote ID is generated and an object is made and similarly in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the quote is created as soon as you interact with the cart for the first time in your current session.

In the code, the object gets created in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::getQuote()`, if no quote id is stored in the session yet:

```
 $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

and saved to the database in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save()`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are looking for `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` -> `public function save()` -> lines:

```
$this->getQuote()->save();
$this->getCheckoutSession()->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
```

which calls `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php` -> `public function save()`.